# Magento 2: Update Handle in xml file

Tags: magento2

can anyone please explain briefly what is the use of update handle, why we are using in layouts in magento2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For a particular page, its layout is defined by two major layout components: page layout file and page configuration file.

A page layout file defines the page wireframe, for example, one-column layout. Technically page layout is an .xml file defining the structure inside the  section of the HTML page markup. Page layouts feature only containers. All page layouts used for page rendering should be declared in the page layout declaration file.

Page configuration is also an .xml file. It defines the detailed structure (page header, footer, etc.), contents and page meta information, including the page layout used. Page configuration features both main elements, blocks of particular classes and containers.

We also distinguish the third type of layout files, generic layouts. They are .xml files which define the contents and detailed structure inside the  section of the HTML page markup. These files are used for pages returned by AJAX requests, emails, HTML snippets and so on.

You can find more information regarding the handles in Magento 2 in the official [guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html).

**Hope it helps!!!**